# How to copy the equation written in MathType into the MSWord in a editable way?

Tags: microsoft-word, mathtype

If I copy the equation written in the MathType into the MSWord, it won't be editable through the MSWord directly, but the MathType itself (the following is how the copied equation shows up in the MSWord):
[image]

And If I double-click on it, the MathType opens up for editing the equation, and it's not editable through the MSWord directly. How can I edit the copied equation within the MSWord rather than MathType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a nice option in the MSWord. First, I should mention my copy preference in the MathType:
[image]

Now I copy the equation and paste it into the MSWord using <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>. Next, I <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on the equation and follow the following steps:
[image]

The equation now is editable through MSWord:
[image]